# Reading Usenet w/o Spam

Tags: spam-prevention, google-groups, usenet

I'm trying to read comp.lang.javascript. The group seems to be active with decent content, but there is so much spam in there.

Currently I'm reading it via Google Groups (http://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.javascript/topics).

Is there a way to read this group without the spam?

Comment: I don't know really know Usenet reader **programs** which have an anti-spam feature. What I can recommend you, though, is to give an eye to Stack Overflow, on the ["javascript" tag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript). It is not an answer directly to your question, but it can be a good source of knowledge and support for you, without spam (or when there is, it is quickly deleted).

Comment: @gnoupi: if you're using an offline reader i wonder if you could hook it up to, say, SpamAssassin, or another external spam filter.  seems the Unix-ish readers might support that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may need to use an actual news reader. The one I'm currently using is [Xnews](http://xnews.newsguy.com/), and it's working well  in Windows 7, despite its relative age. Having a news reader greatly reduces the spam, and you can still use its killfilter if you need to.

Some information regarding free Usenet servers may be found [here](http://www.newsgroupservers.net/free-newsgroup-servers/).

Comment: I had this thought as well. I installed tin (tin.org), but it doesn't seem to filter spam by default. I'm trying to find out if I can get tin to filter it. Do any of those free servers do the filtering server-side?

Comment: I'm using news.aioe.org currently, and about 80-90% of the spam in both rec.arts.int-fiction and rec.games.int-fiction in Google Groups are gone. There's still the occasional spam, but I use the killfilter for that.

Comment: OK using news.aioe.org + kill filter seems to be the best solution so far. Thanks!

Comment: @Isxek Link down..

Comment: @Pacerier: Just checked, it's not.

Comment: @Isxek You linked to http://superuser.com/questions/126051/what-are-some-good-not-too-much-local-spam-and-free-usenet-servers-out-there which is "Page not found"..

Comment: @Pacerier: Sorry, I thought you meant the XNews one. I'm afraid you might have to exercise some Google-fu for free Usenet server links. Here's a link that might help you along: http://www.newsgroupservers.net/free-newsgroup-servers/

Comment: http://xnews.newsguy.com/ link is down